# How to ignore special characters in Tesseract OCR using java

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I have extracted text from image through Tesseract OCR using java. But the output is consisting of some special characters because image contains some symbols.

I want to ignore all the special characters and display just text. Is there any way that i can do that?

Answer (score 1):

In tesseract you can set `TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST` and `TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_BLACKLIST` in order to ignore some special characters.

Following would make tesseract only recognize A-Z and digits

```
String whiteList = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
tessBaseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST,whiteList);
```

Next snippet would allow you to recognize everything except for ~ and ﬂ

```
String blackList = "~ﬂ";
tessBaseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_BLACKLIST,blackList );
```

Also please note that as mentioned in [tesseract github issue](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751) you can't black or whitelist characters with ***tesseract 4.0 Alpha LSTM***, instead you should train LSTM with characters you expect on your image.

Of course if you want - you can still use 3.* versions of tesseract, its tessdata is located [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tree/3.04.00)