# How to whitelist characters in tess4j version 4.1.*

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

The objective is to read number specific data (1,2,...,9,0) from an image.
For this, I'm using Tess4j version 4.1.1.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

My sample code looks like :

```
ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\temp\\number1.jpg"));
ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
instance.doOCR(img);
```

But for some reason, it is misrecognizing some numbers as alphabetic letters. So to minimize the error I need to whitelist only numbers.

As this was possible in earlier Tess4j releases(3.0.**) with [TessBaseAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48702490/how-to-ignore-special-characters-in-tesseract-ocr-using-java), but in current 4.1.* version it's not available.
Can someone help me out here, how to set whitelist characters in TessAPI 4.1.* and later?

Comment: You can't do that in 4+.

Answer (score 0):

The feature is broken since Tesseract 4.00-alpha. It has not been fixed yet.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751

Comment: It is still possible to whitelist only digits with a digits-only tessdata file.

Comment: It has been fixed ! https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/releases/tag/4.1.0